# pandas create new column after merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me

I have 2 dataframes:
1 - dataframe with notifications that i want to send to users

```
notifications_to_send = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['201', '207', '223', '212', '112', '311'],
                   'id_notification': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
                     'email':['user1@gmail.com','user2@gmail.com','user3@gmail.com','user4@gmail.com','user5@gmail.com','user6@gmail.com']
                     })
```

```
   user_id   id_notification    email
0   201             1           user1@gmail.com
1   207             1           user2@gmail.com
2   223             1           user3@gmail.com
3   212             1           user4@gmail.com
4   112             1           user5@gmail.com
5   311             1           user6@gmail.com
```

2 - dataframe with info about users who set option to don't limit the quantity of sending notification to them

```
unlimited_notifications = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['201', '212'],
                   'id_notification': ['1', '2']})
```

```
  user_id   id_notification
0   201           1
1   212           2
```

so I want to add column 'send_push' to first dataframe, that will determine that push will be sent if user set unlimited option
I thought about merge 2 dataframes on user_id  and id_notification

```
notifications_to_send.merge(unlimited_notifications, on=['user_id','id_notification'], how='left')
```

, and for row which fits with this condition 'send_push' will be set on True, if condition don't execute then set it on Null, so it would look like this:

```
  user_id    id_notification    email             send_push
0   201             1           user1@gmail.com    True
1   207             1           user2@gmail.com    null
2   223             1           user3@gmail.com    null
3   212             1           user4@gmail.com    null
4   112             1           user5@gmail.com    null
5   311             1           user6@gmail.com    null
```

so the questions is how to add new column while merge or maybe there is any other way to make it? Compare two dataframes?

Comment: Not sure I'm following - does the `unlimited_notifications` dataframe contains only the users that you want the `send_push` column to be `True`? Does the `id_notification` column on that dataframe have any meaning?

Comment: @jfaccioni I have different notifications, so user can choose which one of them he will always get, if he didn't set unlimited option, for example, notification with id = 1 he will get only once a week, but if he would set this option, i would send this notification 5 times a week

Comment: Hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider accepting one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 2):

Perform left merge then compare the  'id_notification' of both df's and finally assign values according to that:

```
import numpy as np

notifications_to_send=notifications_to_send.merge(unlimited_notifications,how='left',on='user_id',suffixes=('','_y'))
notifications_to_send['send_push']=np.where(notifications_to_send.eval("id_notification==id_notification_y"),True,pd.NA)
notifications_to_send=notifications_to_send.drop(columns='id_notification_y')
```

OR

without `np.where()`:

```
notifications_to_send=notifications_to_send.merge(unlimited_notifications,how='left',on='user_id',suffixes=('','_y'))
m=notifications_to_send['id_notification'].eq(notifications_to_send.pop('id_notification_y'))
notifications_to_send.loc[m,'send_push']=True
notifications_to_send.loc[~m,'send_push']=pd.NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add send_push column to the 2nd dataframe before merging.

When you merge, only the rows where userid and id_notification match the first dataframe will return True.

[image]